# Will followers recharge their own weapons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Related:  [Does my follower's enchanted weapon need to be refilled?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40070/does-my-followers-enchanted-weapon-need-to-be-refilled)

If a follower is given some charged Soul Gems, and an enchanted weapon, will they use the Soul Gems to re-charge the weapon when it is depleted?

Comment: I think your linked question already answers the question with "no".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked question may *imply* no, but it doesn't answer what happens if a follower *has* soul gems.

The answer is still nothing. Now, followers can make it [way easier to *fill* soul gems](http://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/mk9uw/easy_way_to_fill_soul_gems/) (unless this has been patched) by filling an entire stack when they capture a soul, but they won't recharge depleted weapons. In other words, Soul Trap-enchanted weapons will let followers trap souls, but the followers won't use those soul gems to recharge.

*Source:*
Aranea depleting every staff I gave her in my first game while possessing boatloads of soul gems. I also needed to periodically recharge Aela's Bow of Really Fiery Souls (fire + fiery soul trap) manually.

Comment: There's a "firey soul trap" enchantment?  Where?  Nice to know I'm not the only one that likes fire + soul trap on a bow.

Comment: @Iszi You can disenchant the Steel Battleaxe of Fiery Souls found in Ironbind Barrow. The magnitude on the fire (10 pts) is fixed, too, so it's a _very_ cheap way to add a fire enchantment.