# Do enchantments or potion effects that 'Fortify <Magic School>' also affect charge cost of using staves?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm asking based on info from the [UESP wiki's "**Staves**" article](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Staves) (emphasis mine):

> Anyone can use a staff, regardless of magic skill, and using a staff does not use any of the caster's own Magicka; instead, it depletes the staff's charge. **However, the higher the user's skill level in the relevant magic school, the lower the charge cost to use the staff.** Using staves does not increase your skills, nor do staves benefit from higher skill levels, **with the exception of lowering the cost per charge.**

And from a [loading screen message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/danal.jpg):

> The charge level of a staff is based on the corresponding skill of the
>   mage wielding it. For example, a wizard with a high Destruction skill
>   would get a lot of uses from a Staff of Fireball.

I'm wondering if 'Fortify <*magic school*>' alchemy effects or enchantments (make spells cost less to cast), also could affect the charge cost of using a staff of the same magic school.

For example, if I'm wearing a robe or armor like the [Robes of Extreme Destruction or Vampire Armor of Extreme Destruction](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Generic_Magic_Apparel#Fortify_Destruction_with_Regenerate_Magicka) (*Fortify Destruction, 22 pts; Enchantment description: Destruction spells cost 22% less to cast*) – will those apparel lessen the charge cost of using [Destruction staves](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Staves#Destruction) like the Staff of Fireballs or Staff of Ice Storms?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I believe that the Robes/Vampire Armor of Extreme Destruction both have a [Fortify Destruction effect](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim%3aGeneric_Magic_Apparel#Fortify_Destruction_with_Regenerate_Magicka). Or do you mean another thing by "*the example gear you mention don't use Fortify*"?

Comment: No, that's what I meant, but I am apparently just confused. Please ignore. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Most easily seen by enchanting yourself 4x -25% destruction pieces (Helmet/Necklace/Armor/Ring).

If you want to confirm quickly, you can use the console command
`playerenchantobject <object> <effect 1> <effect 2>`
This creates a given item with the given enchantments withe magnitude of your current enchanting skill. So for example - to get a necklace with fortify destruction:

```
playerenchantobject 877f1 7a0f6
```

Combine with `modav enchanting <x>` (or `setav`) to make your enchanting 100 to get a -100% cost item with that command.

Comment: Just launched Skyrim to confirm and this is correct.

Comment: And that means the staff will never be depleted?

Comment: This also works for other spell schools. 4x25% enchants in conjuration make the Sanguine Rose(summons two handed Dremora warriors with Daedric armor and fire enchanted Daedric Greatswords) never run out of charges. A staff of Paralysis will stay full with a set of Alteration gear.

Answer (score 0):

From my hours on Skyrim, if you wear any armor or robes that decrease the cost of spells, then it will NOT decrease the spell for staffs. Although I was only a mage to finish the College of Winterhold questline, I still paid attention.